# "list index out of range" error when using "[" and "]" with regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm currently trying to get an input containing square brackets to work with regex. My code is:

```
#groups of characters
one = r"[a-zA-Z0-9\!\@\$\%\^\*\(]"
two = "[" + r"[a-zA-Z0-9\!\@\$\%\^\*\(][a-zA-Z0-9\!\@\$\%\^\*\(]" + "]"
three = "[" + r"[a-zA-Z0-9\!\@\$\%\^\*\(][a-zA-Z0-9\!\@\$\%\^\*\(][a-zA-Z0-9\!\@\$\%\^\*\(]" + "]"

rawInput = input("Please send text:\n") #raw input
wInput = rawInput.replace(" ","") #whitespace free input
uInput = re.split(r"\s",rawInput) #split input
output = [] #start of output

for i in range(1,(len(wInput))):
  if re.match(one,uInput[i]): #1 char
    output.append("Send {" + str(uInput[i])+"}\n")
  elif re.match(two,uInput[i]): #2 chars
    uInput[i].split()
    output.append("Send {" + uInput[i][1] + "} {" + uInput[i][2] + "}\n")
  elif re.match(three,uInput[i]): #3 chars
    uInput[i].split()
    output.append("Send {" + uInput[i][1] + "} {" + uInput[i][2] + "} {" + uInput[i][3] + "}\n")
```

The issue is that with an input containing any square brackets, I'm given an IndexError: list index out of range. Since I've specified that the square brackets should be separate in `one`, `two` and `three`, why is it still giving an error, and how can I fix it?

Specific error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    if re.match(one,uInput[i]): #1 char
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This works with just single letters, eg "a b c d" would output correctly.

Comment: `uInput[i].split()` does nothing useful... doesn't work in-place

Comment: it's to split the word into letters for the program the output is working in.

Comment: Why are you iterating over `range(1,(len(wInput)))` and using the `i` from this range to index into `uInput`? Are you absolutely sure that `len(wInput) == len(uInput)`? Since you're getting this error, it doesn't seem to be the case

Comment: wInput is one long string - uInput is a list.

Comment: input '[one]' has len 5, uInput has length 1, uInput[i] fails with i=1, has nothing to do with re, the exception tells why

Comment: Wait, so why doesn't `uInput[i].split()` function? Shouldn't it split the iterated word in the list into letters? e.g, "[abc]" becomes "[", "a", "b", "c", "]"?

Comment: No, as stated before, `uInput[i].split()` does not work in place.  You'd have to assign the output to some variable and then use that variable.  Also, the `split` method splits on whitespace, so `"[abc]".split()` would return `["[abc]"]`.  In python you can already use indices on strings (e.g. `"[abc]"[1]` would give `"a"`).  If you really wanted a list, `list("[abc]")` would give you `['[', 'a', 'b', 'c', ']']`.  One of the nice things about python is that it's interpreted, so you can open up an interpreter and try all these things out yourself.

Comment: I've changed the split to a list, assigned it the value twoL/threeL, and adjusted the `uInput[i][1]` to `twoL[1]` and `threeL[1]` - it still has the exact same error as written in my original post above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Kenny Ostrom, answer revealed!

`input '[one]' has len 5, uInput has length 1, uInput[i] fails with i=1, has nothing to do with re, the exception tells why – Kenny Ostrom 2 hours ago`

I was iterating past the length of my input because I used wInput instead of uInput.